# Script for reporting scheduled tasks from server list using credentials(powershell)

Tags: powershell

I'm having some difficulty finding a script that will report the scheduled tasks of a list of remote servers using specific credentials in powershell. Does anyone have any updated script that could satisfactorily accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which operating systems/powershell versions are involved here?

Comment: @briantist Sorry I should've stated that. I will be working with windows server 2003 and 2008. I'm running the script from a windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you can't use `Get-ScheduledTask` since that's way too new. I thought there would be an easy way with WMI but `Win32_ScheduledJob` apparently only works with jobs created by at.exe. In my tests, I couldn't list a single task with that WMI class on local or remote machines!

But this on the other hand, seems to work fairly well:

```powershell
$computer = 'SomeServer'

$svc = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
$svc.Connect($computer)
$root = $svc.GetFolder('\')

$tasks = $root.GetTasks(0)

foreach($task in $tasks) {
    # $task is a task object with useful properties
}
```

I ran this from a Windows 8.1 machine and connected to a Windows 2003 server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content Servers.txt | % { schtasks /Query /U Domain\user /P secret /S $_ /FO CSV /v | ConvertFrom-CSV}
```

Comment: that would work but I need to use credentials to access all of the servers. The credentials are the same for each server. I tried adding a `Get-Credential` command to it did not work. I added it like this: `Get-Content Servers.txt | Get-Credential | %...` I don't think I added it correctly.

Comment: @giacmeister Refer to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx ... Updated Post to use username and password